# How do we prevent the .onTapGesture on other views from firing when SwiftUI menu is visible on the screen?

Tags: swiftui, gesture

Here is my code:

```
/* triggers a full screen view on parent to be able to trap clicks anywhere on the screen and prevent other views .ontap from firing. 

This works when the use taps outside, when the user makes a change but does not work when the user selects the already selected menu item. In that case the menu does disappear but I can't toggle the parent's trapping view because .disappear for the menu or the picker doesn't actually fire.
*/
@Binding var menuShowing: Bool  

....

Menu {
      Picker("Topic", selection: $selectedTopic) {
        Text("Unassigned")
        .tag(nil as Topic?)
        
        Divider()
        
        ForEach(topics, id:\.id) { topic in
            Text(topic.name!)
            .tag(topic as Topic?)
         }
      }
      .onDisappear{
          print("Picker Disappeared") // THIS DOES NOT FIRE IF THE USER SELECTS THE ALREADY SELECTED ITEM
      }
     }
 label: {
         Image(systemName: "circle.grid.3x3.circle")
         .font(.system(size: 26,weight: .ultraLight))
         .foregroundColor(learningSet.topic?.foregroundColor ?? .primary)
         .frame(width:30, height: 30)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onDisappear{ // THIS DOES NOT FIRE IF THE USER SELECTS THE ALREADY SELECTED ITEM
            print("Menu Disappeared")
        }        
        .onTapGesture {
             vm.haptic()
             menuShowing.toggle()
         }

        .onChange(of: selectedTopic, perform: { _ in
            menuShowing = false
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if learningSet.topic != selectedTopic{
                    
                    learningSet.lastModifiedOn = .now
                    learningSet.topic?.lastModifiedOn = .now
                    
                    learningSet.topic = selectedTopic
                    if selectedTopic == nil{
                        vm.unassignedExpanded = true
                    } else{
                        selectedTopic?.lastModifiedOn = .now
                        selectedTopic?.expanded = true
                    }
                    _ = vm.save("Changed Topic for set \(learningSet.name ?? "..") to \(String(describing: selectedTopic?.name))")
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)){
                        forceRefresh.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

This correctly shows the menu and if I select an item, the .onchange fires like it should.

Problem is if the user clicks on some other view on the screen while the is active, it fires that views .onTappedGesture.

I tried different combinations of highPriorityGesture and SimultaneousGesture to no avail.

I also tried the approach of adding a full screen view In between the view with the menu and the underlying views and added an onTap to it. That approach works fine with one issue: If the user click on the currency selected item, the .onChange for the picker doesn't fire, the menu disappears but its .onDisappear doesn't fire. So there is no way to know the menu is no longer visible, and hide my full screen view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: where in your code, is the `.onTappedGesture`, the `.onChange`, the `.onDisappear` and the `...user click on the currency selected item` you keep talking about? It is best to show a minimal reproducible code, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated to include .onDisappear, .onTapped and .onChanged.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work but found a decent solution.
Essentially switched to using Buttons to construct the Menu elements and disabled the button for currently selected Topic. This prevents the user from selecting it, forcing an external tap or a change, both of which work fine.

Would still like to understand why the code above doesn't work, but hopefully the alternate approach helps someone out.